# Auto click a Button when script/page loaded

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to a little script that would click a button when the page is loaded or even better when the script XYZ.js is loaded.

The script I have done works, but only if I add a delay to it. Which is a bit confusing because it normally should also work without adding a delay.

**WORKS**

```
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
    var button = document.querySelector(".myJS-Button");
        if (button) {
            button.click();
        }
    }, 1);
});
```

**DOESN'T WORK**

```
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
    var button = document.querySelector(".myJS-Button");
    if (button) {
        button.click();
    }
});
```

Comment: Where/how is `XYZ.js` added to the page?

Comment: Consider doing something like `document.addEventListener( 'DOMContentLoaded', function() { document.querySelector( 'script[src="XYZ.js"i]' ).addEventListener( 'load', function() { alert( "loaded" ) } ) } )`

Comment: What does the `<button>` do? Scripted events - such as `click` - are passed with the [`EventObject.isTrusted`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/isTrusted) property set as `false` ([see demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/84m1Lo3u/1/)), this means that some actions that require a user-initiated event won't take place. Unfortunately I can't find a reference for which events shouldn't be trusted, but it seems to be a general safeguard.

Comment: The script is being loaded by the header (<script async src="XYZ.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>). Looks like the script XYZ.js is rendering the button a bit later then the page load itself.

Answer (score 0):

it's likely because the button hasn't fully loaded or rendered by the time the script is executed
try this instead :

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    var button = document.querySelector(".myJS-Button");
    if (button) {
        button.click();
    }
});
```

edit :
im not sure what's the problem i tried the same code with  a link  and it worked :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <a class="myJS-Button" href="google.come" target="_blank">BUTTON</a>
  </body>
  <script>
    window.addEventListener("load", function () {
      var button = document.querySelector(".myJS-Button");
      if (button) {
        button.click(); 
      }
    });
  </script>
</html>
```

Comment: I did try that too, but whiteout luck.
I also think their is some kind of rendering delay that defeats this addEventListener.

Comment: does ur button do anything when clicked ? i tried the code with a link and it worked 
i added my code in the answer

Answer (score 0):

It worked liked this

html file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="./index.js" defer></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button class="button" onclick="showmessage();">My Button</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

Javscript File

```
const button = document.querySelector(".button");

button.click();

function showmessage() {
  console.log("Button Was Cliked");
}
```

Here's the console

[image]

Comment: The problem is that the external JavaScript renders the button a bit later.
Looks like I need something that simply monitors for a few seconds after the page has loaded if a XZY button appears and then clicks it automatically.